# How to set a Onpropertychanged method from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a Class which inherits from ViewModelBase.  I need to set the getter setter from other class.  How to get this

```
    public class UserScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public UserScreenViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<TabDataItem>();
        try
        {
            .....
                var allLayouts = context.PANEL_LAYOUTS;

                foreach (var layouts in allLayouts)
                {
                    TabDataItem item = new TabDataItem()
                    {
                        Header = layouts.Header,
                    };
                    this.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            this.SelectedTabItem = this.Items[0];
        }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<TabDataItem> Items { get; set; }

    private TabDataItem selectedItem;
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the SelectedTabItem.
    /// </summary>
    public TabDataItem SelectedTabItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedItem;
        }
        internal set
        {
            if (this.selectedItem != value)
            {
                this.selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabItem");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now I need to set the SelectedTabItem from other class instead of "this.SelectedTabItem = this.Items[0]".  How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you saying `SelectedTabItem` is an inherited property?

Comment: I don't understand very well your question. Do you want to set 'this.SelectedTabItem = this.Items[0]' from another class, let's say 'AnotherClass' ?

Comment: You would need to have a reference to the `UserScreenViewModel`.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Yes. From some 'Another class' I need to set the SelectedTabItem.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
public class NotificationClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TabDataItem selectedItem;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

     /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the SelectedTabItem.
    /// </summary>
    public TabDataItem SelectedTabItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedItem;
        }
        internal set
        {
            if (this.selectedItem != value)
            {
                this.selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTabItem");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

You need to register event handler for this if its related to specific property

```
protected void OnSelectedTabItemChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler handler = SelectedTabItemChanged;;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}

public event EventHandler SelectedTabItemChanged;
```

Register even handler function for this in class where you want to raise event and call your function.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your comment, I think you should do something like this:

```
public class UserScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public void SetSelectedTabItem()
   {
      this.SelectedTabItem = this.Items[0];
   }
}

public class NewClass
{
   public UserScreenViewModel UserViewModel {get; set;}

   public NewClass(UserScreenViewModel userViewModel)
   {
       this.UserViewModel = userViewModel;
       this.UserViewModel.SetSelectedTabItem();
   }
}
```

Obviously, you need to reference the current instance of your `UserScreenViewModel` in the property of `NewClass`, that you can do in the initialization of the program, in the code behind of your main view, using this pseudo-code:

```
public class MainView
{
   public MainView()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      var userViewModel = new UserScreenViewModel();
      this.DataContext = userViewModel();
      var newClass = new NewClass(userViewModel);
   }
}
```

Anyway, I suggesting this approach because it's not clear why you're trying to do this, instead of directly access the property setter. I think maybe because you're using several projects and this could be the reason of choosing the `internal` access modifier. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. The `SelectedTabItem` property setter has `internal` visibility, so unless the OP is using multiple projects (which the OP really should clarify in the question if that is the case), the property setter should be accessible already.

Comment: @hvd Yes, it could be a little bit complicated. The OP, indeed, doesn't specify if he's using multiple projects and I think this is the reason why he asked this question. Otherwise, like you said, the property setter should be already accessible.